# Cefsharp CLR initialization crash in MFC project

Tags: mfc, clr, nuget-package, cefsharp

I created a CLR class as DLL and loaded cefsharp,cefsharp winforms,cef core through Nuget package in vs 2015.When I run it in a sample MDI CFormView application it works.But when I try to run it in my main MDI application which loads COM DLL it crashes without any errors.The code never executes and crashes even before initialisation.I am using it like below

```
    using namespace cefsharp;
    using namespace cefsharp::winforms:
    Cef:: Initialize (gcnew CefSettings());
```

The debugger never comes to this place and application crashes.I am really unable to debug since it doesn't even hit initinstance if I write that line but if I don't write that line the app runs.

Comment: From a CefSharp point of view this isn't a scenario that's supported.  You might have better luck directly implementing CEF.

Comment: Thankyou.But my doubt being it running on other apps of similar configurations.But as of now even writing anything referring to cefsharp:: makes application crash or not load at all.

Comment: There are MFC examples using CEF. CefSharp requires vc++, that might be the problem,  or it could be the COM threading model isn't compatible.

Comment: You can try CefGlue or ChromiumFx if you absolutely have to use a .Net based CEF wrapper.

Comment: @amaitland.Thanks a lot.I will definitely check that out.

Comment: @amaitland..Update ...I once again thankyou for your feedback..I have crossed the hurdle now..The browser is loading on the view.Thankyou once again for your effort on this.

Comment: Great, if you think the information is useful to others you can self post an answer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem somehow resolved when I created a CLR inside my project and added the needed dependencies for it.Now I am able to load my MDI applications with different views and also Initialize the COM dll without encountering any crash.